# Call read() returns 0 but buffer changed, not happened when call fread() to read the same offset

Tags: c, fread, fseek

if I read file by calling read() like this:

```
unsigned char buf[512];
memset(buf, 0, sizeof(unsigned char) * 512);
int fd;
int readcount;
int offset = 10315001; /* file size is 14315504 */

fd = open("myfile", O_RDONLY);
lseek(fd, offset, SEEK_SET);
readcount = read(fd, (void*)buf, 8);
close(fd);
```

the read() returns 0, but the memory of "buf" has been changed(not 0 any more). And if I tried to read the same offset and same file with fread() like this:

```
FILE* file;
file = fopen("myfile", "r");
fseek(file, offset, SEEK_SET);
readcount = fread((void*)buf, 8, 1, file);
fclose(file);
```

fread() returns 0 either, but the buf is as same as before.

if read() failed, why it changes the memory space of "buf"? Or did I make some mistakes?

Thanks for help : )

**Edit: Every time I ran the code above, the "buf" changed by read() in the *same way* -> from 0 to the *same values*. So the changed "buf" may not be *random values*?**

**Edit 2: The offset parameter is valid(thanks twalberg), and if I read another valid offset, both read() and fread() will be succeeded and the result of "buf" is the same. Is there any way to find what's wrong when read() failed? The errno is "No errors" when read() returns 0.**

Comment: How do you know that the buffer changed? After `unsigned char buf[512];`, you have no idea what `buf` contains.

Comment: Actually, even if i memset the buf with 0, the result is the same

Comment: Is `offset` past the end of the file? If so, then both `read()` and `fread()` are supposed to return 0, but as noted in other answers, there are no guarantees made about the state of `buf` by either call.

Comment: The offset parameter is valid(thanks twalberg), and if I read another valid offset, both read() and fread() will be succeeded and the result of "buf" is the same.

Comment: It's not an error for `read()` to return `0`. That just means no bytes were read, not that something went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found what's going on here.
The file is a binary one, but I read() it with text mode(O_RDONLY).

The value of offset 10315001 is 0x1a, when read() and fread() function meets 0x1a in text mode, they both will return 0, **but the different is, the read() will still write the buf with binary mode, while fread() won't do this.**

Answer (score 2):

The contents of the buffer after an unsuccessful call to `read()` or a successful zero-byte `read()` are undefined.

Likely what happened is that it allocated an internal (possibly kernel-side) buffer for temporary storage (which got filled with different garbage) and copied the buffer into your buffer, but didn't actually write to its buffer.

Since you only need to examine the buffer after a successful read, this shouldn't matter. If you have important data in that buffer, move it out of there before passing it to a function that might erase that data!

**Edit:** The code could look like this. Imagine `kernel_read()` is the syscall to read from a file descriptor, and it takes a buffer that was allocated in the kernel's address space rather than the process' address space (because kernels do seemingly strange things like that.)

```
extern __kernel void *kernel_malloc(size_t size);
extern void kernel_copy_from_kernel_to_userland(void *dest, __kernel void *src, size_t size);
extern void kernel_free(__kernel void *address);

extern int kernel_is_valid_fd(int fd);
extern ssize_t kernel_read(int fd, __kernel void *kbuf, size_t count);

ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count) {
    ssize_t result = -1;

    if (0 == kernel_is_valid_fd(fd)) {
        __kernel void *kernelbuf = kernel_malloc(count);
        if (kernelbuf) {
            result = kernel_read(fd, kernelbuf, count);
            kernel_copy_from_kernel_to_userland(buf, kernelbuf, count);
            kernel_free(kernelbuf);
        } else {
            errno = ENOMEM;
        }
    } else {
        errno = EINVAL;
    }

    return result;
}
```

This is a *thought experiment*, not a real implementation from any shipping operating system, but perhaps it can help you understand why you might have seen what you saw.

Comment: Hm, do you have references on the undefined content one? I cannot find it in the manpages.

Comment: Well yeah. It's not defined in the manpages. That's kind of what I mean. The POSIX standard does not say anything will or won't happen to the buffer in those cases. (Also, your manpages may be different from mine--this is likely implementation-specific behaviour.)

Comment: Good argument actually (the point with: nothing is said, thus its undefined). I just thought there was some source stating „reading from a read buffer beyond an offset of the return value is undefined“ or alike.

Comment: Every time I ran the code above, the "buf" changed by read() in the same way -> from 0 to the same values. So the changed "buf" may not be random values? Or inter the read() function, each time it found errors and stopped in the same place? But the errno is "No errors" all the time, which makes me confused.

Comment: I see no evidence to backup your claim about the buffer contents being undefined. As far as I can tell, since there's no language allowing the buffer to be modified if no data is read, it must be unmodified.

Comment: Since the buffer contents after a failed call are not defined to be anything, they are undefined. Nowhere does it say they will be unmodified.

Comment: I think I've found what's going on here. The file is a binary one, but I read() it with text mode(O_RDONLY). The value of offset 10315001 is 0x1a, when read() and fread() function meets 0x1a in text mode, they both will return 0, but the different is, the read() will still write the buf with binary mode, while fread() won't do this.

Comment: There is almost never a good reason to open a file in text mode. :)